# NodeJS 6 crypto complaining about digest in deprecation message?

Tags: node.js, node-crypto

I'm trying to use the native crypto module in my NodeJS application, but I keep getting the deprecation message:

> (node:26) DeprecationWarning: crypto.pbkdf2 without specifying a
>   digest is deprecated. Please specify a digest

I know this is due to a change set that expects a digest moving forward:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4047

However, from what I can see, my code is following the syntax exactly [as outlined in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback).  Anyone else see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function verify (password, expected, callback) {
  const combined = Buffer.from(expected, 'base64')
  const saltBytes = combined.readUInt32BE(0)
  const hashBytes = combined.length - saltBytes - 8
  const iterations = combined.readUInt32BE(4)
  const salt = combined.slice(8, saltBytes + 8)
  const hash = combined.toString('binary', saltBytes + 8)
  return crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, hashBytes, 'sha512', (err, verify) => {
    if (err) return callback(err, false)
    return callback(null, verify.toString('binary') === hash)
  })
}
```

**Note**: If it makes any difference, this is executing inside the [slim version of the node:6](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

Comment: Interesting...if I run this outside of the docker container I'm not getting the message... will dig more into this...

Answer (score 0):

After much digging I finally figured it out.  It has nothing to do with the code segment above.  I'm using the [iron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iron) module which is currently at version 4.0.0. The current published version doesn't pass an argument for the digest, which is causing the warning message to be produced.

They've [already committed code to correct this](https://github.com/hueniverse/iron/blob/d34d01947c5d58952d69cc0a10bf2b2e20c8a27c/lib/index.js), but it hasn't been published yet.  This should resolve itself soon.